# What is the correct syntax for inner struct literals in Go?

Tags: go

I would like to initialize A with all its inner structs in a literal form.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    B struct {
        C struct {
            D string
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    x := A{B{C{D: "Hello"}}}
    y := A{B.C.D: "Hello"}

    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

What is the correct syntax?

I need this to build structs for XML marshaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the literal type for structs when building [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

This makes it rather tedious if using only anonymous types. Instead, you should consider declaring each struct separately:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    B B
}

type B struct {
    C C
}

type C struct {
    D string
}

func main() {
    x := A{B: B{C: C{D: "Hello"}}}
    // x := A{B{C{"Hello"}}} // Without using keys

    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

**Edit:**

Initializing the struct with anonymous types as shown in your example, would look like this:

```
x := A{struct{ C struct{ D string } }{struct{ D string }{"Hello"}}}
```

Comment: This fattens the scope of the inner structs and leads to name space collisions, if an inner struct has the same name as an outer struct. And it makes the structs almost unreadable, if used for deeply nested XML data. Is there no way to keep B local to A?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't declare types within the scope of another type. As mentioned, you can use anonymous structs. I've edited it into the answer, but I wouldn't say that is an option either. About namespace conflicts, you could solve that by naming the struct types A, AB, ABC instead of A, B, C.

Comment: In case it helps, if you Printf("%#v") the "edit" from ANisus, you have: `main.A{B:struct { C struct { D string } }{C:struct { D string }{D:"Hello"}}}`